# How add white space b/w td's ? Which Css i need to use from Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a view in mvc4 using normal HTML . I have to use Bootstrap css and need to design a responsive screen .
**MY code :**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="~/Content/Images/Add.png" height="28" width="28" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td> <a href="www.google.com"> <h4>New</h4> </a> 
                    <td>
                        <img src="~/Content/Images/delete.png" height="28" width="28" />
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td> <a href="www.google.com"> <h4>Delete</h4> </a> 
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/Content/Images/export.png" height="28" width="28" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td> <a href="www.google.com"> <h4>Export</h4> </a> 
                            <td>
                                <img src="~/Content/Images/SearchAdvanced.png" height="28" width="28" />
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td> <a href="www.google.com"> <h4>Advanced Find</h4> </a> 
                                <td>
                                    <img src="~/Content/Images/MoreActions.png" height="28" width="28" />
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td> <a href="www.google.com"> <h4>More Actions</h4> </a> 
                                </td>
                            </td>
                        </td>
                    </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

I need to Display all the images with hyperlink text beside In-line .  How how to make the above code responsive and give white space between each action

Edit1 : When i apply below peice of code the images and text are apperaring with more space and filling entire screen .

```
<div class="table-responsive">

<table  class="table">
```

Regards

Comment: this is your code http://jsfiddle.net/vishnurajv/WCMFp/ what change u want??

Comment: i don't think you can add space between tds, but you can increase the paddings to add white

Comment: vishnurajv : i need to add white space b/w pNew & Pdelete AND the second thing is those columns will come in one line right so when i reduce the view port size the columns should come one below other @bootstrap..

Comment: daniel : Ty for reply . yes paddings nice one will try that and please look into other part of my question @bootstrap . Actually till date i tried Bootstrap responsive css applied on tables,div where rows will be appreared one below other .